# missing word in edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.FastDictionary:getWord-dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, sphinx

I am trying to change something on demo of the Sphinx4 java

The grammar used is

```
public <numbers> = (Able |ABY | Angamaly | Six ) * ;
```

I added the lines

```
ABRAHAM              EY B R AH HH AE M
ABY                  AH B AY
ANGAMALY             AE N G AE M AH L IY
```

to

> TIDIGITS_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz\edu\cmu\sphinx\model\acoustic\TIDIGITS_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz\dictionary

But I get the error

```
12:18.170 WARNING dictionary        Missing word: able
                   in edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.FastDictionary:getWord-dictionary
12:18.180 SEVERE tidigits           Can't find HMM for AH
                   in edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.TIDIGITS_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.Model:lookupNearestHMM-tidigits
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.getHMMStates(FlatLinguist.java:1196)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.expandUnit(FlatLinguist.java:1171)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.attachUnit(FlatLinguist.java:983)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.expandPronunciation(FlatLinguist.java:917)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.expandWord(FlatLinguist.java:840)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.expand(FlatLinguist.java:748)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist.compileGrammar(FlatLinguist.java:319)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist.allocate(FlatLinguist.java:232)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.allocate(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:576)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.allocate(Decoder.java:109)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.allocate(Recognizer.java:182)
    at demo.sphinx.hellodigits.HelloDigits.main(HelloDigits.java:52)
```

The path is set correctly 
The program works well if we dont edit the dictionary file in TIDIGITS_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz

The default dictionary file looks like this

```
eight                EY_eight T_eight
five                 F_five AY_five V_five
four                 F_four OW_four R_four
nine                 N_nine AY_nine N_nine_2
oh                   OW_oh
one                  W_one AX_one N_one
seven                S_seven EH_seven V_seven E_seven N_seven
six                  S_six I_six K_six S_six_2
three                TH_three R_three II_three
two                  T_two OO_two
zero                 Z_zero II_zero R_zero OW_zero
```

Comment: Is the difference in your pronounciation notation significant?

Comment: I am not talking about a pronunciation error. This is Java compile error